# AMQ org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SizeRotatingFileHandler not creating a log file

Tags: jboss-logging, jboss-amq

AMQ 7 running on Linux 
Current default configuration:

```
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
```

Attempted to convert to:

```
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SizeRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,maxBackupIndex,rotateOnBoot,rotateSize,fileName
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.maxBackupIndex=2
handler.FILE.rotateOnBoot=true
handler.FILE.rotateSize=5K
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
```

Results in no log file being created.

Verified jboss-logmanager-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar contains

6196  Defl:N     2786  55% 07-25-2017 04:59 16cae5b1  org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/SizeRotatingFileHandler.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use the configuration you specified I get this exception when I start the broker:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5K"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.getValue(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:448)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$1.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:205)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$1.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:335)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:288)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:546)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:514)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:476)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.<clinit>(Artemis.java:40)
```

The problem is this line of your configuration:

```
handler.FILE.rotateSize=5K
```

[The code expects a valid Java `long` value](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/2.0.7.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/SizeRotatingFileHandler.java#L185) which represents the number of bytes which are written to the file before rotating.  `5K` translates into `5120` (5 * 1024).  When I used this value everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Knocked it down for testing and saw the docs had 2M as default. Didn't translate that 2M logical value.